# How do I open project version 1.0 with xcode 4.2?

Tags: xcode

I downloaded this Xcode project(version 1.0 as in `contents.xcworkspacedata`) from [here](http://nehe.gamedev.net/data/lessons/macosxcocoa/lesson31.zip)

When I try to open it, got this error:

```
Failed to load project at '.../Lesson31_OSXCocoa/Lesson31_OSXCocoa.pbproj', incompatible project version.
```

How do I open project version 1.0 with xcode 4.2?

Comment: IMHO, I think you'd be better off using Blender to make the models, then import it using more recent code sample.

Answer (score 7):

**You're better off trying to find a newer tutorial, or just studying the code as-is, without expecting to build and run it.**

Judging by the modification dates, this code is almost ***ten years old***.  Even if you can get a modern version of XCode to open it, there's no reason to think that the headers, libraries, etc., that it needs to compile and run will still be compatible.  Moreover, ten years is a long time in software terms.  While some of the content might still be applicable, it certainly won't be anywhere near the cutting edge (which itself won't be new by the time you've mastered it).

---

All that said, if you're really intent on working with that project file in XCode 4.2, the best way is probably to convert it the same way a continuously developed project would have: XCode by XCode.

- You can download older versions of XCode from Apple [here](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action) (requires free Apple developer account).
- Some older version will be able to import that file and update it to a newer format.
- Assuming you don't stop at that point and use that version of XCode, you can repeat the process with the updated project file and ever-newer versions of XCode until you've arrived at version 4.2.

Answer (score 6):

Relatively easy to make a new project and add the appropriate files to it.  Took less than 10 minutes (had to update the code in a few places). Note that I didn't spend much time cleaning up this old code - quite a few deprecated warnings. But it runs and works. I have Xcode 4.3.2 installed but hopefully you'll be able to open it with 4.2. Here's a link to it: [Lesson31.zip](http://geekanddad.com/Downloads/Lesson31.zip)

Note that the process for doing this (so you can do it for any others), is to create a new Mac OS X  Cocoa Application project, add the files (except main.m) from the old project to the new project, and then add necessary libraries to fix link errors (OpenGL Framework).  If there's a nib then you can open that in Xcode and copy the window with view and controller out of that project and paste them into the .xib file created with the new project.  Then fix compiler warnings/errors as necessary (add a few (char*) coerces, remove reference to std::ios::nocreate which doesn't seem to be available, etc).